# Create a save & print to word button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to the VBA coding. I am currently making a ms access db for printing official letters using mail merge. I have already make that happen. Now I want to make a button that saves the current record to db and simultaneously print to word file using the mail merge option.

It will be really helpful for me if you solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a word document that uses mail merge feature and gets its information from the access db. When I use this code it does not open the word document with the current information. It opens the word document with the last saved information.

If I open the word document on its own, from the task bar, it asks if I want to run the SQL and I click yes and everything operates normally. I want to click a button from within access to accomplish this same task to open the contract.

here is the code if it can help:-

```
Private Sub Command205_Click()

Dim LWordDoc As String
Dim oApp As Object

'Path to the word document
LWordDoc = "C:\Users\.....k Up\01- Proposal\contract.docx"

If Dir(LWordDoc) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Document not found."
Else
    'Create an instance of MS Word
    Set oApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    oApp.Visible = True
    'Open the Document
    oApp.Documents.Open FileName:=LWordDoc
End If
```

End Sub